# Is it possible to take a screenshot when it show " Couldn't save screenshot"?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

[**Couldn't save screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce9Bs.png)

I have searched for " secure-flag " text in that app by using APK Parser. But didn't find any.

So, is there any method to take screenshot on android app that doesn't allow to take screenshot??

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of that security measure, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. But it was an educational app. and I paid them to subscribed one of their course but they don't allow me to download my lecture sheet. I think they kill my right.

Answer (score -1):

may be accomplished by the following ways :

- install a screen recorder and record video of the screen. you can then take screenshot of the video later.
- install a connector/app to view your phone screen in your PC and then take the screenshot in the PC.

hard way [can cause stability issues. not recommended]: reverse engineer the app and remove such restrictions. then do whatever you wish with the app